# Unrecognized attribute disableAlternativeTemplates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, umbraco7

Unfortunately I added a reference from another project in my solution instead of only copy pasting the libraries, So I think my assemblies got overridden.

Now I'm getting this error and I think its coming from umbraco.

Does anyone here had the same issue?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'disableAlternativeTemplates'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error: 


An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Source File: D:\WWW\website\config\umbracoSettings.config    Line: 153 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34249
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to find the solution for this error. Fortunately I have a backup of my website that I restored so the website is working again.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the exact same problem, but found if you overwrite the existing Umbraco Dlls, with the original ones, it fixed it

Ian

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of wasted hours, I also could not ever fix this issue, even after following Ian's advice above.  I introduced this problem by upgrading a 7.1.6 site to 7.4.3.  I did the upgrade incrementally, every 3 or 4 releases through Nuget, but the mistake I made was not running the site in between upgrades.

Running the site updates config files, and database values, etc and skipping that step was my kiss of death.  So I guess this isn't really a solution, but more of how you can prevent it.

BTW - I went back and did the upgrades again (with bigger jumps between versions actually), ran the site after each upgrade, and it went perfectly.